# Is it ok to display error message in place of iAd if it fails to load?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, iad, appstore-approval

*First of all, this is not a programming question, but still this is the most appropriate site to ask it, since it's still development-related.*

I know that according to Apple, the app should hide the iAd banner if no ads were loaded. I could do that, this is not what I'm asking.

I plan to add iAd to a game, and there would also be an option (in-app purchase) to remove ads. Now if I implemented the iAd banner like Apple advises (hiding it if no content is available) then it would be really easy for anyone to hide ads without paying extra. They would just turn on airplane mode so the device cannot connect to the internet, and the iAd banner would go away.

But since I'm interested in revenue (who isn't?) I don't want users to be able to remove the banner without paying. So I made my app to display a black banner (same size as iAd banner) saying "iAd could not be loaded" in place of the iAd banner if it fails to load any ads (and if the purchase to remove them wasn't made yet). This way users can only recover that portion of the screen via the in-app purchase to remove ads.

I know it sounds a bit cruel, but come on. iAds and in-app purchases are for revenue. I think there's no problem with patching an "exploit" to hide ads while not paying for that.

My question is that will my app get rejected for this? Is it okay to do? Since Apple advises to hide the banner if there are no ads in it, I don't think they will like it, even though I think it's totally reasonable. What do you think?

Comment: In one of my approved apps , i have a banner which shows up untill iAD are loaded

Comment: What does that banner look like? Does it say anything?

Comment: It's a custom add with iCons of my other apps , redirects to app store.

Comment: Nice. I don't have any other apps yet, so I might just redirect to this one in the app store (like a "rate" button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't specifically reference iAd in the banner, but rather simply state something like 'pay to remove ads to make this ugly banner go away'. I have not seen specific requirements from Apple in this area, but I am sure they would have no problem with a big irritating banner at the bottom of your app if it didn't reference their technologies directly. So you don't run the risk of angering Apple, and you still get your irritation revenue.

Comment: I will try to submit it anyway, and see what happens. This is a good advice though, I will not say "iAd" there.

Comment: Let us know what happens. Might be good to know for reference.

Comment: I'm in mid-development, so it will take a while to complete the game. But I will update the question once the app got reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience submitting to Apple, this will not be considered acceptable. That guideline is strict. They would much rather nothing be displayed than some generic banner that doesn't follow their design rules.

It might not be too bad; I'm not sure about this, but in Airplane Mode, iAd still caches recent ads. Additionally, you'd have to enter Airplane mode, which would disable your internet. I think that a smaller proportion of users that you might think will be willing to do this regularly.